# Special character issue in slowly changing dimension?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am using Slowly Changing Dimension task from SSIS 2008 for delta load. Flat file is the input to slowly changing dimension task. I have observed that '--' character from file is converted into ' â€' after delta load.

Input is the flat file and destination is the database table. Flat file contains few strings having '--' character but somehow after inserting this data to table this character is getting converted to 'â€'.

What can be the issue?

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Regards,
Sameer K.

Answer (score 0):

In essence you need to scrub these characters from the data. This can be done in several places, but it's a well accepted design pattern to populate from the source file to a staging table where you can scrub the offending characters before bringing it into your slowly changing dimension. It's also possible to scrub the file prior to import, but it's typically easier to work with the data once it's in a database rather than in a flat file. You could also include a derived column task within SSIS to extract these characters one in the SSIS Pipeline, but you would need to manage this column by column which can become difficult to maintain.